# Toolbar button doesnt get accessed at all

Tags: vbscript, qtp

I am using the following code but the toolbar button doesnt get accessed at all. The error is "unknown error"

```
Window(window_name).WinToolBar("Example Toolbar").Press "Print"
```

Here Example Toolbar is added to the object repo, and gets highlighted correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure the error is **Unknown Error** and not **Cannot identify the specified item of the Standard object...**.

Perhaps you're using the wrong name, this will give you the names of the items in the `WinToolBar`

```
MsgBox Window(window_name).WinToolBar("Example Toolbar").GetContent()
```

Comment: Failed to run the test due to an unknown error.

Line (317): "msgbox( Window(window_name).WinToolBar(""Example Toolbar").GetContent())".

Comment: @Onnesh, in that case I don't know what may be wrong, can you try to do `Window(window_name).WinToolBar(""Example Toolbar").Highlight` and see if it works (as it does from the repository).
BTW if I didn't solve your problem why did you accept my answer? You have a better chance to get a helpful answer if you don't accept this one. (It also seems strange to me to accept an answer and not up-vote it but that may just be me...)

Comment: it seems the problem got solved, the highlight may not be needed. since i didnt know the steps how it got solved but after I used ur code and removed it, the steps suddenly worked correctly :)